# Creating script that takes matrices of size n and size n x 1

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a MATLAB function that takes a matrix of length n, and uses gaussian elimination with partial pivoting to compute Ax = b. A is n x n, and b is n x 1.

I'm trying to create a script that generates random numbers and then call the function with those numbers. So far I have

```
A = rand(n)
b = rand(n, 1)
genp(r, r)
```

but since n is undefined, it doesn't work. Is the best way to create the variable n and assign a random integer to it?

Comment: See: [`randi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html).

Comment: Yes...? Since you're ( I assume) creating a test script, picking some arbitrary size for the test system is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the best way is to create a variable `n`. What you want is (probably):

```
n = 10;       % Change this if you want different sized data
A = rand(n);
b = rand(n,1);
genp(A,b);
```

This way you can very easily alter the size of your data, by simply changing `n`. Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070531/matlab-genp-for-system-of-2n1-equations-antidiagonal-and-diagonal), I'm assuming you want `gen(A,b)`, and not `gen(r,r)`, as you wrote in your question.

If you want an random `n` every time you call the function, check out [`randi`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html)

Comment: Thanks! If I wanted n to be a random integer between 1-10, how would I do that?

Comment: @jqdc2224. did you check out the `randi` link in the answer?

Comment: How would I get a matrix with 2n+1 x 2n+1 dimensions? I'm trying to use randi(10, 2n+1) but I get Unexpected MATLAB expression

Comment: `2*n+1` is valid syntax, not `2n+1.